# For Each Row in Range - Incorrect Row Iteration

Tags: excel, foreach, transpose, vba

I'm creating a single-column index file from multi-row/-cell source data in Excel. I have two worksheets - a source and destination - in a single workbook. Iterating through each row (11 in dev, ~15,000 in prod) of the source worksheet the `For Each` loop I wrote should:

- Find the first empty cell in Column A of the destination worksheet
- Use `LastCell.Value =` to input a set value in that cell
- Use `LastCell.Offset(r, c).Value =` to pair a set value with a copied value from each cell in a single row of the source worksheet to the next destination cell down. There are eight to be copied and a ninth that is set

The loop works perfectly **once**, then fails to iterate to the next row. Each subsequent loop shifts copied values up by one and leaves the set values, with blanks, in place. It does this once for each cell in the source row and only after that does it move on to the next row down.

When I say set value I'm referring to what is in quotes, and copied values are those of the `Row.Offset`.

The code is:

```
Sub Export_Index_File()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim sr As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Source Data")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Index File")
Set sr = ws1.Range("A2:H13")

For Each Row In sr.Cells
    Set LastCell = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    LastCell.Value = "Begin Doc"
    LastCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Account Number: " & Row.Offset(0, 0).Value
    LastCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "Account Type: " & Row.Offset(0, 1).Value
    LastCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = "Date: " & Row.Offset(0, 2).Value
    LastCell.Offset(4, 0).Value = "Doc Type: " & Row.Offset(0, 3).Value
    LastCell.Offset(5, 0).Value = "File Path: " & Row.Offset(0, 4).Value
    LastCell.Offset(6, 0).Value = "Institution: " & Row.Offset(0, 5).Value
    LastCell.Offset(7, 0).Value = "Name: " & Row.Offset(0, 6).Value
    LastCell.Offset(8, 0).Value = "TIN: " & Row.Offset(0, 7).Value
    LastCell.Offset(9, 0).Value = "End Doc"
Next Row

End Sub
```

Here are two output examples. Successful on the left, unsuccessful on the right:

```
Begin Doc                  |Begin Doc
Account Number: 123456     |Account Number: Checking
Account Type: Checking     |Account Type:01/01/2001
Date: 01/01/2001           |Date: Statement
Doc Type: Statement        |Doc Type: 123456.pdf
File Path: 123456.pdf      |File Path: 123
Institution: 123           |Institution: Jane Doe
Name: Jane Doe             |Name: 123-45-6789
TIN: 123-45-6789           |TIN:
End Doc                    |End Doc
```

Notice the one-line shift up. To fix this, I changed the loop to read `For Each Row In sr.Rows` but received Type 13 Mismatch errors.

I copied this code from a working spreadsheet before expanding it to include more rows. It is nearly identical to the working code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was proof-reading my post the answer dawned on me. I don't know how I missed this small error or what 'clicked' in my head to recognize it, but I answered my own question. I still feel a value in posting this in case others experience a similar problem.

The reason the code was looking at all eight cells in each row is because I told it to. While setting the variable for the source range, I mistakenly thought I needed to encompass all the data:

```
Set sr = ws1.Range("A2:H13")
```

This is incorrect. I only need the first column and the code would sort out the rest of the cells using my `Offset` commands. The working code is:

```
 Set sr = ws1.Range("A2:A13")
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer! It'll be of use to others possibly, so no harm accepting it when you can, and you'll get a few rep.

Comment: Indeed! SO is making me wait two days before I can accept my own answer. I do hope the answer is useful to some.